# Как связать два класса между собой?

Tags: javascript

Ребята кто силен в JS, подскажите пожалуйста. Как получить данные о названии школы?
Хотелось бы в классе Children получить ссылку на класс School для того что бы не дублировать данные из за наследования.

```
class Sсhool{
    nameScool;
    constructor(setNameScool){
        this.nameScool=setNameScool;
    }
    addChildren(children){
        this[children.nameChild] = children;
    }
}

class Children{
    constructor(setName, setAge){
        this.nameChild = setName;
        this.ageChild = setAge;
    }
    getInfo(){
        console.log(`Учится в школе - ${this.nameScool}`)
    }
}

const school = new Sсhool('Школа 1');
const alex = new Children("Alex", 12)
school.addChildren(alex)

alex.getInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Sсhool{
    nameScool;
    constructor(setNameScool){
        this.nameScool=setNameScool;
    }
    addChildren(children){
        this[children.nameChild] = children;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.nameScool;
    }
}

class Children{
    constructor(setName, setAge, school = null){
        this.nameChild = setName;
        this.ageChild = setAge;
        this.school = school;
    }
    getInfo(){
        let info = `Имя: ${this.nameChild}, возраст: ${this.ageChild}, `;
        info += this.school ? `учится в школе «${this.school.getName()}»` : 'в школе не учится';        
        console.log(info);
    }
}

const school = new Sсhool('Школа 1');
const alex = new Children("Alex", 12, school)
alex.getInfo()
```